# Which lstm architecture for my data and what data process should I do

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm, loss-function, convergence

I'm trying to build LSTM architecture to predict sickness rate(0%-100%). My input is an array with dimension 4760x10 (of number of sick persons per town per age, number of consultation .....) My output or the y is the sickness rate.

I'm new in machine learning and I tried several tips like changing the optimzer, the layer node number and the dropout value and my model didn't converge(the lowest mse was =616.245). I tried also to scale my data with 'MinMaxScaler'. So could you guys help me with some advice to change the architecture or some data processing to help the model to converge.

here is the lstm model which give me the mse=616.245

```py
def build_modelz4():
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(1, 10), return_sequences=True))
 model.add(LSTM(84, return_sequences= True))  
 model.add(LSTM(84, return_sequences=False))  
 model.add(Dense(1,activation='linear'))
 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_squared_error'] )
 model.summary()
 return model
lstmz4 = build_modelz4()
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="weightslstmz4.hdf5", verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
newsclstmhis = lstmz4.fit(trainX,trainY,epochs=1000,batch_size=221, validation_data=(testX, testY) ,verbose=2, shuffle=False, callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

Notice that when I used the ann model it converge with mse=0.8. So with lstm it should converge 
and thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you using LSTM? Is your data time-series data? With your input shape of 4760x10, it seems 4760 is the number of people and 10 is the number of features. Do you have samples that have been obtained over time?

Comment: 4760 is the weeks per town the prediction is far a way from the y true

Comment: I see. Using LSTM with input_shape=(1, 10) does not make sense. You are setting the number of time steps to 1, which means that you are not using the history to predict the future. Rather, start 'chopping' your data into chunks of time series data, like each sample with 12 time steps, and then fit LSTM to the new data.

Comment: @SaTa how to do that please ?

Answer (score -1):

4760 is a very small number of dimensions for a LSTM.Plus its seems like a very simple classification model try using simpler algorithms like svm for  the process but if you are adamant on using deep learning use Sequential model with Dense layer instead with few more layers than this one that should definitely give you better results.